# Problems with array as state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

jsx transforming tool throws an error saying 'unexpected token: [' on the following line:

```
this.setState({array[index]: value});
```

Obviously I want simply to set new state but this error forced me to write some workarounds. Why isn't the transformer accepting the above line?

Answer (score 5):

Simply because it's not valid Javascript (or JSX for that matter). You want something like this:

```
array[index] = value;
this.setState({array: array});
```